# Probability of card distribution of lowest four cards in a suit.

Tags: probability, card-games

Inspired by a game of solo Spades I recently lost. In a four player game where all 52 cards are distributed evenly.  If the lowest card I have in a suit is the 5, what is the probability the 2, 3, and 4 are distributed evenly among the other three players?

I only had a few seconds to bet, but my intuition would be that the odds were pretty low.  If the cards were evenly distributed, I would almost definitely lose (unless another player did something really dumb).  If not, I was guaranteed a win (unless I did something stupid). I bet on my intuition but ended up losing.

Was my intuition correct and I just go unlucky or was I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Total number of ways of distributing the $3$ cards to your opponents:

$$3^3$$.

Favorable outcomes (even distribution):

$$3!$$

Therefore required Probability is:

$$\frac{6}{27}$$
$$=\frac{2}{9}$$

Comment: Actually, in this case, it would be unfavorable outcomes, as that was the only way I could lose.  (See my edit to the question)

Comment: So my intuition was correct and I just got unlucky.  Thanks

Comment: What I mean by favorable outcomes is that these are the ones that you asked for, i.e., even distribution. Wrote that in the bracket as well.

Comment: Yeah, I just meant that in the general sense of the term, this happening was not a good thing for me.  Wasn't trying to correct your terminology

Comment: Yeah sure. No problem. But yeah, the probability of even distribution is about $22\%$, so about $3$ out of $4$ there won't be even distribution.